# CRM 2015 Add SSRS report to dashboard without panels, toolbars, scrollbar

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I work with crm2015.
I added diagram, made from reporting services on CRM Dashboard as IFrame. But with it added toolbar, scrollbar and other thinks that exists from reports.

[image]

Add params like &rc:Toolbar=false does not works becouse CRM 2015 is differents by CRM 2011 and URL is different:
http://192.168.3.220/VEGAS/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=run&helpID=LeadProjectBudgets.rdl&id=%7b36A8D870-0974-E511-80BF-00155D00059D%7d

Can I hide this panels from CRM options or SSRS options or exists some another ways to do it?

Comment: Just render your report in an HTML web resource. Add the web resource to your dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use approach similar to following - http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2012/05/embed-context-report-to-left-navigation.html

General idea - is not use HTML webresource and embed report inside it and hide unneeded controls using JavaScript called from html webresource code.

Comment: I can not go to link that you wrote. Can you check it and write it again?

Comment: Try this one - http://butenko.pro/2012/05/ms-crm-2011-embed-context-report-to-left-navigation-pane/ I migrated my blog :)